# Meteor: adding react component from npm with browserify – js vs jsx

Tags: meteor, reactjs, npm, browserify

I'm trying to add this react component to my meteor project:
https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout

I added this with standard browserify/npmhacks process. When I run the app initial thereafter, I receive this error:

```
Marks-MacBook-Air:meteor-app markshust$ meteor --settings settings/dev.json
  [[[[[ ~/Sites/meteor-app ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
  npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- react-native-swipeout, externalify...
=> Errors prevented startup:

  While processing files with cosmos:browserify (for target web.browser):
lib/app.browserify.js: Unexpected token (53:6) while parsing file:
  /Users/markshust/Sites/meteor-app/packages/npm-container/.npm/package/node_modules/react-native-swipeout/index.js

While processing files with cosmos:browserify (for target os.osx.x86_64):
lib/app.browserify.js: Unexpected token (53:6) while parsing file:
  /Users/markshust/Sites/meteor-app/packages/npm-container/.npm/package/node_modules/react-native-swipeout/index.js

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

When I pull up line 53 of https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout/blob/master/index.js, it's hitting some jsx. The file is named with a .js suffix, so it appears Meteor is having a problem when it runs into the jsx code.

I'm assuming this is a common problem when using react components from npm with meteor. How does one easily resolve this?

Many thanks!
Mark

*packages.json*

```
{
  "react-native-swipeout": "2.0.8",
  "externalify": "0.1.0"
}
```

*lib/app.browserify.js*

```
Swipeout = require('react-native-swipeout');
```

*lib/app.browserify.options.json*

```
{
  "transforms": {
    "externalify": {
      "global": true,
      "external": {
        "react": "React.require"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native-swipeout peer dependencies react-native
so you need add react-native in packages.json or package.js add Npm.depends

meteor 1.3 still use node0.10, but react-native need node 0.12,so react-native-swipeout need waite meteor 1.4 for use

$MONGO_VERSION = "2.6.7"

$NODE_VERSION = "0.10.45"

$NPM_VERSION = "2.15.1"

$PYTHON_VERSION = "2.7.10"